# Outer margin in a CorePlot graph

Tags: plot, frame, core-plot, padding, margins

Does anybody know how to get rid of the outer margin of the plot area frame in a CorePlot graph? I don't have too much available space in my iPhone app for displaying it so I would like the plot area frame to match the whole view dimensions.

[image]

taking in consideration:
[image]

Modifying the padding doesn't affect the outer margins but the internal ones.
Any suggestion would be really appreciated!

thanks a lot!

Claus

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Which padding did you change? This should enlarge the plot area frame to fill the space:

```
graph.paddingLeft = 0.0;
graph.paddingTop = 0.0;
graph.paddingRight = 0.0;
graph.paddingBottom = 0.0;
```

Eric